# SSIS error handling: redirect rows that have zip code field more than 5 from a flat file

Tags: sql-server, ssis, load, zipcode

I have been given a task to load a simple flat file into another using ssis package. The source flat file contains a zip code field, now my task is to extract and load into another flat file that accepts only the ones with correct zip code which is 5 digit zip code , and redirect the invalid rows to a new file.

Since I am new to SSIS, any help or ideas is much appreciated.

Comment: Is all you're checking is that it's 5 digits? That leaves lots of possiblities for invalid zip codes.

Comment: yes. I want to direct rows with matching 5 digits to one flat file and the other zip codes (more than 5 digit) to other flat files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a derived column which determines the length of the field. Then you can add a conditional split based on that column.  <= 5 goes the good path, > 5 goes the reject path.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but it turns out that it was something else I was asked to do. It's handling the error caused by one or more rows  like zip code with more than 5 digits without failing the task.

Comment: Heck, just truncate it then.